# How to delete the row from datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Friends, I'm using datagridview in my windows C# application. We know that When the form with datagridview is loaded a default row is created in the grid. If we type anything in any cell(I've total 6 columns, 2 hidden columns), a new row is created. But if we delete the entry the newly created row is not deleted. In this way we can create as many row we want without keeping any value inside any cell. I want the datagridview to maximum create 2 such rows and when in both the rows, no value is present, the last row to be deleted (so that grid will have 1 row without any data in it). I've tried to remove row in datagridview1_CellValueChanged event, but it's not working. Which event should I use and how can I get the desired functionality? Please help.

Comment: Please show us the code of your attempts as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Comment: you can use row index or DataGridView1.SelectedRow

Comment: @Sukanya I believe that 'row' is a thing called a variable. If you type the code into this thing called Visual Studio, you will find that it has a thing called a 'type' associated with it, which I believe is a DataGridViewRow.

Answer (score 0):

We have two function to remove rows from DataGridView

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Remove();
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt();
```

you can provide the index of the row as parameter to remove the row.

You can give in Validating or Validated event of DataGridView

Comment: I know we've these two functions but in which event and what row index should I use to remove the row?

Comment: when you want to delete the row after the user to insert data

Comment: just try in the Validating or Validated.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop using the same grid RowCount it won't work

```
  for(int i = 0;i<dataGridMaster.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
               dataGridMaster.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
```

It Will not do the job correctly because the Count of rows changes while looping.

Instead assign the number to a local variable like:

```
Int loopNum = dataGridMaster.Rows.Count;
for(int i = 0;i<loopNum ;i++)
            {
               dataGridMaster.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A default row is automatically added to allow for user input.  If you don't want this, set the DataGridView `AllowUserToAddRows` property to false.

```
dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Making it effectively a read-only grid.